# Octopus kanji: 章魚 vs 蛸 vs 鮹

Tags: kanji-choice, animals

I'm trying to determine the most appropriate kanji for タコ (octopus), and have come across three possibilities: [章魚](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%AB%A0%E9%AD%9A), [蛸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%9B%B8), and [鮹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%AE%B9).

- According to [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E8%9B%B8), all three possibilities are read as たこ.
- The Pocket Kenkyusha Japanese Dictionary ([ISBN 978-0-19-860748-9](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=!ISBN+978-0-19-860748-9)) includes 蛸.
- The Collins English-Japanese Dictionary ([ISBN 0-00-719655-5](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=!ISBN+0-00-719655-5)) only gives タコ.

My question: How common is each variant, and are their meanings truly equivalent?　For example:

- 英語でタコは「octopus」です。
- 英語で章魚は「octopus」です。
- 英語で蛸は「octopus」です。
- 英語で鮹は「octopus」です。

My understanding is that any of the above could be considered *correct* (though some would seem more unusual than others) and that they all have the exact same meaning.

Comment: Never learned to write たこ/タコ in kanji in school.  And I went to school in the only Japanese-speaking country in the world, in case you are wondering.

Comment: @l'électeur Yes, my impression was that it's not usually written in kanji. To clarify the intent of my question slightly: Imagine a written test where one of the questions was "How would you write 'Octopus' in Japanese?" - would the kanji examples given above be considered "technically correct, but unusual", or simply "wrong"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at 漢字, then 蛸 is by far the most common option. This is confirmed by the frequency data in the BCCWJ (Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese, via http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp):

```
タコ　 676 results
蛸　　 129 results
ダコ　  32 results
章魚　  10 results
鮹　　   2 results
鱆　　   0 results
```

タコ is still a lot more popular than any 漢字 version. (But that's to be expected since, like many other 漢字 for animals, 蛸 is not 常用漢字 and 熟字訓 readings are very rare.)

Of course, 蛸 can also be written in ひらがな. It's not easy to get numbers, but even looking at たこやき alone, we already get big numbers:

```
たこ焼　244 results
タコ焼　 39 results
蛸焼　　  1 result
```

Just something to keep in mind when choosing whether to write in 漢字 or not.

---

*Edit.*

The dictionary 大辞林 entry for たこ is

> **たこ** [1]
>   【<sup>▼</sup>蛸・〈章魚〉・<sup>▼</sup>鮹】
>   [...]

The notation <sup>▼</sup> means that the *kanji* is not 常用漢字 and the angled brackets mean that the reading is 熟字訓. As such, writing たこ as 蛸 or 章魚 or 鮹 wouldn't be seen as incorrect, but unusual.

Comment: [There's also a parsed version of BCCWJ available](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/N.04245/#tabinfo), and although parsers like this aren't perfect, we can look at the numbers they give: 676 `タコ`, 129 `蛸`, 32 `ダコ`, 10 `章魚`, and 2 `鮹` (If you haven't accepted the agreement, you may need to click the link again after doing so; go to the 基本 tab and click 書字形 to see the numbers for yourself.)

Comment: @snailboat Ooh, great. More than half was a reasonable estimate then.