# The different ways to write "fox"

Tags: spelling

When writing "fox", what is the difference between these two ways?
狐
 or 
キツネ

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20840/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31148/9831 /